# Portfolio Variance of a Portfolio of N Assets in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, portfolio, variance

Portfolio variance is calculated as:

```
port_var = W'_p * S * W_p
```

for a portfolio with N assest where

```
W'_p = transpose of vector of weights of stocks in portfolios
S = sample covariance matrix
W_p = vector of weights of stocks in portfolios
```

I have the following numpy matrixes.

Array (vector) of weights of stocks in the portfolio (there are 10 stocks):

```
weights = np.array(
     [[ 0.09],
      [ 0.05],
      [ 0.15],
      [ 0.10],
      [ 0.15],
      [ 0.15],
      [ 0.08],
      [ 0.08],
      [ 0.1 ],
      [ 0.05]])
```

Covariance matrix of stock returns:

```
covar = np.array([[ 0.00154474  0.00079555  0.00099691  0.00052596  0.0005363   0.00062005
0.00064031  0.00037494  0.00018826  0.00132809],
[ 0.00079555  0.00287429  0.00058536  0.00091774  0.00046885  0.00110434
0.00137141  0.00046724  0.00030414  0.0016615 ],
[ 0.00099691  0.00058536  0.00155757  0.00056336  0.00052395  0.00060104
0.00057223  0.00021365  0.00017057  0.00130247],
[ 0.00052596  0.00091774  0.00056336  0.00126312  0.00031941  0.00088137
0.00024493  0.00025136  0.00011519  0.00135475],
[ 0.0005363   0.00046885  0.00052395  0.00031941  0.00054093  0.00045649
0.00042927  0.00021928  0.00016835  0.00093471],
[ 0.00062005  0.00110434  0.00060104  0.00088137  0.00045649  0.00133081
0.00060353  0.0003967   0.00024983  0.00168281],
[ 0.00064031  0.00137141  0.00057223  0.00024493  0.00042927  0.00060353
0.00468731  0.00059557  0.00020384  0.00078669],
[ 0.00037494  0.00046724  0.00021365  0.00025136  0.00021928  0.0003967
0.00059557  0.00082333  0.00017191  0.00066816],
[ 0.00018826  0.00030414  0.00017057  0.00011519  0.00016835  0.00024983
0.00020384  0.00017191  0.00036348  0.0004505 ],
[ 0.00132809  0.0016615   0.00130247  0.00135475  0.00093471  0.00168281
0.00078669  0.00066816  0.0004505   0.00530036]])
```

When I compute

```
weights.T * covar * weights
```

The result is an array the same size as covar. I am new to portfolio theory but I would imagine that the variance of the portfolio should be a scalar (single value).

Does anyone have experience with this that might help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(covar,weights))
# array([[ 0.00064654]])
```

For 2D numpy arrays, `np.dot` is equivalent to matrix multiplication.

For a 2D array np.dotted with a 1D array, `np.dot` is equivalent to matrix-vector multiplication.

For 1D arrays, `np.dot` is equivalent to the inner product.

For numpy arrays, the `*` performs element-wise multiplication (with [broadcasting](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) if necessary).

---

```
weights.T*np.matrix(covar)*weights
#matrix([[ 0.00064654]])
```

Alternatively, if you convert `covar` to a `np.matrix`, then `*` is equivalent to matrix multiplication.

Comment: @strimp099 - As a side note, with newer versions of numpy (>= 1.5, I think?) `dot` is also an ndarray method. In other words, you can write the first example in unutbu's example as `weights.T.dot(covar.dot(weights))`.  For some things this style is a bit cleaner, albeit a bit less backwards-compatible.